# Compare 2 rows and 2 columns and find the differences

Tags: sql, sql-server

Raw Data

```
+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| RowNum | SeqNo |     Col1      |     Col2      |     Col3      |     Col4      |     Col5      |     Col6      |
+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | A123  | A             | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | Z             | 'emptystring' |
|      2 | A123  | 'emptystring' | B             | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | D             |
|      1 | B123  | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | C             | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' |
|      2 | B123  | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | D             | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' |
|      1 | C123  | A             | 'emptystring' | B             | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' | 'emptystring' |
|      2 | C123  | 'emptystring' | A             | 'emptystring' | B             | 'emptystring' | A             |
+--------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Desire Result:

```
+-------+---------------+----------+
| SeqNo |  From_Value   | To_Value |
+-------+---------------+----------+
| A123  | A             | B        |
| A123  | Z             | D        |
| B123  | C             | D        |
| C123  | 'emptystring' | A        |
+-------+---------------+----------+
```

How can I get desired result? Desired result is to capture the changes were made (based on desired result). EmptyString is blank NOT NULL just whitespace.

SeqNo is unique number and will not be duplicated (in Raw Data).

RowNum=1 = From_Value = Col1, Col3, Col5 (these would not be change)

RowNum=2 = To_Value = Col2, Col4, Col6 (these would not be change)

Comment: By `'emptystring'`... do you mean `null`?

Comment: Great job posting sample data and desired output. However the explanation doesn't make sense. You state that "SeqNo is unique number and will not be duplicated" but it is in your output on two rows. And no idea what the rules are here for the output.

Comment: I think I may understand what you want but it begs the question. Can you fix the tables because this does not appear to be properly normalized and will always be a pain to work with.

Comment: Ummm even with your edit SeqNo is duplicated. In fact it appears twice for each value in your raw data. Still the rules here are not clear. Please try to explain the logic of why A-B and Z-D for A123. It is because that the first value in row1 and row2? That further my concern that the real issue is the table design.

Answer (score 0):

To find these "changed values" you can use the following query:

```
with
from_to as (
  select t1.seqno, t1.col1 as f, t2.col2 as t
  from t t1
  join t t2 on t1.seqno = t2.seqno and t1.rownum = 1 and t2.rownum = 2
  union  
  select t1.seqno, t1.col3 as f, t2.col4 as t
  from t t1
  join t t2 on t1.seqno = t2.seqno and t1.rownum = 1 and t2.rownum = 2
  union
  select t1.seqno, t1.col5 as f, t2.col6 as t
  from t t1
  join t t2 on t1.seqno = t2.seqno and t1.rownum = 1 and t2.rownum = 2
)
select seqno, f as from_value, t as to_value
from from_to
where f is null and t is not null
   or f is not null and t is null
   or f <> t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #Raw (
        RowNum int,
        SeqNo nvarchar(20),
        Col1 nvarchar(max),
        Col2 nvarchar(max),
        Col3 nvarchar(max),
        Col4 nvarchar(max),
        Col5 nvarchar(max),
        Col6 nvarchar(max)
    )
insert #Raw values
    (1, 'A123', 'A', '    ', '    ', '    ', 'Z', '    '),
    (2, 'A123', '    ', 'B', '    ', '    ', '    ', 'D'),
    (1, 'B123', '    ', '    ', 'C', '    ', '    ', '    '),
    (2, 'B123', '    ', '    ', '    ', 'D', '    ', '    '),
    (1, 'C123', 'A', '    ', 'B', '    ', '    ', '    '),
    (2, 'C123', '    ', 'A', '    ', 'B', '    ', 'A')


select  f.SeqNo, f.Col1 [From_Value], t.Col2 [To_Value]
    from #Raw f
    join #Raw t on
        t.SeqNo = f.SeqNo
        and t.RowNum = 2
        and f.Col1 <> t.Col2
    where
        f.RowNum = 1
union
select  f.SeqNo, f.Col3 [From_Value], t.Col4 [To_Value]
    from #Raw f
    join #Raw t on
        t.SeqNo = f.SeqNo
        and t.RowNum = 2
        and f.Col3 <> t.Col4
    where
        f.RowNum = 1
union
select  f.SeqNo, f.Col5 [From_Value], t.Col6 [To_Value]
    from #Raw f
    join #Raw t on
        t.SeqNo = f.SeqNo
        and t.RowNum = 2
        and f.Col5 <> t.Col6
    where
        f.RowNum = 1


drop table #Raw
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that only uses one join.

```
DECLARE @RowData TABLE(RowNum INT, SeqNo VARCHAR(10), Col1Before VARCHAR(10), Col1After VARCHAR(10), Col2Before VARCHAR(10), Col2After VARCHAR(10), Col3Before VARCHAR(10), Col3After VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @RowData
VALUES
    (1, 'A123', 'A', '', '', '', 'Z', ''),
    (2, 'A123', '', 'B', '', '', '', 'D'),
    (1, 'B123', '', '', 'C', '', '', ''),
    (2, 'B123', '', '', '', 'D', '', ''),
    (1, 'C123', 'A', '', 'B', '', '', ''),
    (2, 'C123', '', 'A', '', 'B', '', 'A')

SELECT
    ColumnChange.SeqNo
    ,ColumnChange.BeforeValue
    ,ColumnChange.AfterValue
FROM
    @RowData AS BeforeRow
    INNER JOIN @RowData AS AfterRow
        ON BeforeRow.SeqNo = AfterRow.SeqNo
            AND BeforeRow.RowNum = 1
            AND AfterRow.RowNum = 2
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT
            SeqNo
            ,TableColumn
            ,BeforeValue
            ,AfterValue
        FROM
            (VALUES
                (BeforeRow.SeqNo, 'Col1', BeforeRow.Col1Before, AfterRow.Col1After),
                (BeforeRow.SeqNo, 'Col2', BeforeRow.Col2Before, AfterRow.Col2After),
                (BeforeRow.SeqNo, 'Col3', BeforeRow.Col3Before, AfterRow.Col3After)
            ) AS ColumnChange(SeqNo, TableColumn, BeforeValue, AfterValue)
        WHERE
            ColumnChange.BeforeValue IS NULL AND ColumnChange.AfterValue IS NOT NULL
            OR ColumnChange.BeforeValue IS NOT NULL AND ColumnChange.AfterValue IS NULL
            OR ColumnChange.BeforeValue != ColumnChange.AfterValue
    ) AS ColumnChange
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Raw TABLE(
        RowNum int,
        SeqNo nvarchar(20),
        Col1 nvarchar(max),
        Col2 nvarchar(max),
        Col3 nvarchar(max),
        Col4 nvarchar(max),
        Col5 nvarchar(max),
        Col6 nvarchar(max)
    )

insert @Raw values
    (1, 'A123', 'A', '    ', '    ', '    ', 'Z', '    '),
    (2, 'A123', '    ', 'B', '    ', '    ', '    ', 'D'),
    (1, 'B123', '    ', '    ', 'C', '    ', '    ', '    '),
    (2, 'B123', '    ', '    ', '    ', 'D', '    ', '    '),
    (1, 'C123', 'A', '    ', 'B', '    ', '    ', '    '),
    (2, 'C123', '    ', 'A', '    ', 'B', '    ', 'A')


SELECT SeqNo,value_from,value_to FROM
(
SELECT SeqNo, 1 as _lp, RowNum, Col1 as value_from ,LEAD(Col2,1,Col1) OVER(PARTITION BY SeqNo order by RowNum ) as value_to FROM @Raw
UNION ALL
SELECT SeqNo, 2 as _lp, RowNum, Col3 as value_from ,LEAD(Col4,1,Col3) OVER(PARTITION BY SeqNo order by RowNum ) as value_to FROM @Raw
UNION ALL
SELECT SeqNo, 3 as _lp, RowNum, Col5 as value_from ,LEAD(Col6,1,Col5) OVER(PARTITION BY SeqNo order by RowNum ) as value_to FROM @Raw
) as tab
WHERE value_from!=value_to 
order by SeqNo,_lp
```